# Pagination Component not rendered on UI - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in my react application [using this guide](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/03/14/react-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google)  I created the Pagination.js file as instructed in the guide, but I am not able to see that on my UI, here is the screenshot of the application[image]

Here is my Search Results Page where I am implementing pagination, basically this will show the results fetched from the server based on user entered keyword and hence I want to show as paginated results. My js file corresponding to the above screenshot is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';
import SearchPageResultsStyle from "../assets/css/SearchResultsPage.css"
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class SearchResultsPage  extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Printing in the results component: this.props.location.state.data.keyword")
        console.log(this.props.location.state.data.keyword)
        this.state = {
            results: this.props.location.state.data.results,
            keyword: this.props.location.state.data.keyword,
            pageOfItems: []
        };
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    }

    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
        // update local state with new page of items
        this.setState({pageOfItems});
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <NavigationBar/>
                <h4 style={{textAlign:'center', color:'#1a0dab'}}>Showing search results for <span style={{fontWeight:'bold', fontStyle:'Italic'}}>'{this.state.keyword}'</span></h4>
                <hr/>
                <div className={'wrap'} style={SearchPageResultsStyle}>
                    <div className={'fleft'}>left column</div>
                    <div className={'fcenter'}>
                        <h3 style={{color:'#1a0dab'}}>Tweeter tweets text will be displayed here!!!</h3>
                        <a href={'https://google.com'}>Tweet urls will be displayed here</a>
                        <br/>
                        <div style={{display:'inline'}}>
                            <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}}>topic: </span>crime</p>
                            <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}}>city: </span>delhi</p>
                            <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}}>lang: </span>Hindi</p>
                            <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}}>Hashtags: </span></p>
                            <hr/>
                            <Pagination items={this.state.results} onChangePage={this.onChangePage}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'fright'}>right column</div>
                </div>
            </div>


        )
    }

}

export default SearchResultsPage;
```

My pagination.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    initialPage: PropTypes.number,
    pageSize: PropTypes.number
};

const defaultProps = {
    initialPage: 1,
    pageSize: 10
};

class Pagination extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pager: {}
        };

        // set page if items array isn't empty
        if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length) {
            this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        // reset page if items array has changed
        if (this.props.items !== prevProps.items) {
            this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
        }
    }

    setPage(page) {
        var { items, pageSize } = this.props;
        var pager = this.state.pager;
        
        if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }

        // get new pager object for specified page
        pager = this.getPager(items.length, page, pageSize);

        // get new page of items from items array
        var pageOfItems = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);

        // update state
        this.setState({ pager: pager });

        // call change page function in parent component
        this.props.onChangePage(pageOfItems);
    }

    getPager(totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) {
        // default to first page
        currentPage = currentPage || 1;

        // default page size is 10
        pageSize = pageSize || 10;

        // calculate total pages
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        var startPage, endPage;
        if (totalPages <= 10) {
            // less than 10 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 6) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 10;
            } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 9;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 5;
                endPage = currentPage + 4;
            }
        }

        // calculate start and end item indexes
        var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        var pages = [...Array((endPage + 1) - startPage).keys()].map(i => startPage + i);

        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }

    render() {
        var pager = this.state.pager;

        if (!pager.pages || pager.pages.length <= 1) {
            // don't display pager if there is only 1 page
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="pagination">
                    <li className={pager.currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setPage(1)}>First</button>
                    </li>
                    <li className={pager.currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)}>Previous</button>
                    </li>
                    {pager.pages.map((page, index) =>
                        <li key={index} className={pager.currentPage === page ? 'active' : ''}>
                            <button onClick={() => this.setPage(page)}>{page}</button>
                        </li>
                    )}
                    <li className={pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)}>Next</button>
                    </li>
                    <li className={pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.totalPages)}>Last</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Pagination.propTypes = propTypes;
Pagination.defaultProps = defaultProps;
export default Pagination;
```

I do not understand that why my list of items in Pagination.js file is not getting rendered.
Can anybody point out what exactly is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I implemented the above library, it's really cool library. I have to add css to it, to make it look good. It is working for me now.

```js
import React from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';
import SearchPageResultsStyle from "../assets/css/SearchResultsPage.css"
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class SearchResultsPage  extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Printing in the results component: this.props.location.state.data.results")
        console.log(this.props.location.state.data.results)
        this.state = {
            results: this.props.location.state.data.results,
            keyword: this.props.location.state.data.keyword,
            pageOfItems: []
        };
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    }

    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
        // update local state with new page of items
        this.setState({pageOfItems});
    }
    render() {

        const renderItems = this.state.pageOfItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3 style={{color: '#1a0dab'}} key={index}>{item.text}</h3>
                    <a href={'https://google.com'} key={index}>{item.tweetUrl}</a>
                    <br/>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>topic: </span>{item.topic}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>city: </span>{item.city}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>lang: </span>{item.lang}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>Hashtags: </span></p>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <NavigationBar/>
                <h4 style={{textAlign:'center', color:'#1a0dab'}}>Showing search results for <span style={{fontWeight:'bold', fontStyle:'Italic'}}>'{this.state.keyword}'</span></h4>
                <hr/>
                <div className={'wrap'} style={SearchPageResultsStyle}>
                    <div className={'fleft'}>left column</div>
                    <div className={'fcenter'}>
                        {renderItems}
                        <Pagination items={this.state.results} onChangePage={this.onChangePage}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={'fright'}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default SearchResultsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a misplaced `if` statement in the `constructor`. So this:

```
class Pagination extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pager: {}
        };

        // set page if items array isn't empty
        if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length) {
            this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
        }
    }
```

Should be:

```
class Pagination extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pager: {}
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length) {
            this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, I believe that those lines are for rendering data that says item1, item2, item3 and so on, it does not have any relation with the buttons on the bottom of the page. I might be wrong, just thought so, btw I tried your way and unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: My apologies I have misinterpreted your question, but I think I might have found the bug, I have since edited my answer.

Comment: componentWillMount() is deprecated in the latest react version, and, soon it will be removed in the upcoming major release, that's why I put the logic inside the constructor.  Anyways I tried using componentWillMount() function, but again, it is not working.